# Trigonometry - Find the exact value of $\sin15^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

I am having problems understanding how to solve $\frac{1}{4}(\sqrt6 - \sqrt2)$, find the exact value of $\sin15^\circ$.

I have the answer, but I need help understanding the methods to achieve the answer. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Using the law of cosines in the figure, we have
$$
x^2 = 1^2 + 1^2 - 2.1.1\cos 30^{\circ} = 2 - \sqrt{3} \quad \Rightarrow \quad x = \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2}}{2}
$$
and the law of sines
$$
\dfrac{\sin 15^{\circ}}{x} = \dfrac{\sin 150^{\circ}}{1} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \sin 15^{\circ} = \dfrac{x}{2} =  \dfrac{\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2}}{4}
$$
Note that 
$$
2 - \sqrt{3} = \dfrac{8 - 4\sqrt{3}}{4} = \dfrac{6 - 2\sqrt{6}\sqrt{2} + 2}{4} = \dfrac{(\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2})^2}{4}
$$

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

$15=60-45$ or $45-30$

Use $\displaystyle\sin(A-B)=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B$

---

Alternatively, $$\cos2A=1-2\sin^2A\iff\sin^2A=\frac{1-\cos2A}2$$

Now, $0<15<90\implies \sin15^\circ>0$

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice way to derive this one geometrically, as with many trig expressions.  And the answer is certainly on the internet if you give it a quick google.  but rather than link you, i'll give you a hint at what image to consider. 
The idea in these derivations is often similar:
Try to construct an image out of triangles which you know about, (45-45-90) or (30-60-90) triangles, such that in some way (sometimes requiring some cleverness) a new triangle is formed whose interior angles satisfy your needs.  in this case we want to get a (15-75-90) triangle.

As a start, try drawing a triangle with angles 30-45-105.  You can split this into two special triangles, a 30-60-90 triangle and a 45-45-90 triangle.  Now look for a way that you can add a 15-75-90 triangle to make your 30-45-105 triangle into a nice special right triangle. there are a few ways to do this.

once you have this diagram, you can express the lengths of the hypotenuse and leg opposite to the 15 degree angle in terms of some unit length side.